# Firefox Won't Save My Google Cookies Between Restarts

Tags: firefox, cookies

I'm using firefox 11 on Ubuntu.

For some strange reason, Firefox won't save my google cookies between browser restarts. I have to log in to gmail every time I restart my browser, even if I click on the check box that tells Google to remember me.

The strange thing is that Firefox does actually store some gmail cookies when I log in. It's just that those cookies disappear after restarting Firefox.

The especially strange thing is that this only seems to happen with *.google.com url's. I haven't noticed this problem with any other site that I use.

Please note that I tried to see if this was a plugin-related problem. I therefore started Firefox in safe mode and turned off all plugins. I then logged into Gmail and told it to remember me. I then shut down Firefox and started it the same way in safe mode. I got the same bad results.

Has anyone else ever seen anything like this before? Is there a reason that Firefox seems to be blacklisting Google cookies?

Comment: You disabled plugins. How about add-ons/extensions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say "addons" above, not plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, here is what fixed it for me:

Go to `Options> Privacy` then click **Exception** button  and type `www.google.com` and click **allow**. Now close the `exceptions -Coolkies` window and click ok and restart your browser.

Comment: Well what do you know? Next to "goole.com" it said "allow for session". Thanks!